# How do I parse a function’s parameter from its string representation in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

`var str = "?$Expand=User($filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'First'&$Select=Name),Role($filter=contains(Name, 'admin' )), Group";`

My input is **User** and need to get inside string like "$filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'First'&$Select=Name"

If pass input is **Group** it will return empty

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Get the index of the first '(' and last ')', then get the substring that's in between.

Comment: You can use regex for that

Comment: `string result = Regex.Match(source, @"(?<=\().*(?=\))").Value;` or `string result = source.Substring(source.IndexOf('(') + 1, source.LastIndexOf(')') - source.IndexOf('(') - 1);`

Comment: It would be better to use code formatting and include the double quotes describing exactly what is inside the string. For example, is this correct `"functionName($filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'first')"` ?

Comment: var str = "?$Expand=User($filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'First'&$Select=Name),Role($filter=contains(Name, 'admin' )), Group";       My input is User and need to get inside string like "$filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'First'&$Select=Name"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var str = "functionName($filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'test')";

var pattern = new Regex(@"^([^\(]+)\((.*)\)$");

var match = pattern.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("function: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("arguments: " + match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: Obviously, this assumes that `functionName` is known upfront, and that the string exclusively includes the function call. That’s consistent with the OP’s request, but it’s worth acknowledging in case the data format might vary.

Comment: "functionName($filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'test'), 
    functionName123($filter=substring(Name,1) eq 'tessdsdsdst') "  - above string not working

Comment: Ah, thought this to be some magic constant. Adjusted my answer accordingly - feel free to look into a tutorial on regular expressions to understand how to define your own ones.